# Concept related to precision of float and double

Tags: floating-point, double, precision, ieee-754, floating-accuracy

Why the precision of the `float` is up to 6 digits after the decimal point and the precision of the `double` is up to 15 digits after the decimal point?

Can anyone give a *mathematical explanation* of it?

Answer (score 1):

Saying the precision of `float` or `double` is some number of decimal digits is sloppy terminology. `float` and `double` are commonly implemented using the IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64 formats, which use significands of 24 and 53 bits, respectively. (The significand is the fraction portion of a floating-point representation. It is accompanied by a sign bit and an exponent.) The precisions of these formats are 24 bits and 53 bits.

The precision is sufficient that, for `float`, any decimal numeral with six significant digits can be converted to `float` accurately enough that conversion back to a six-digit decimal numeral produces the same number. (All conversions discussed herein use round-to-nearest.) Six is the limit; there are some seven-digit decimal numerals that do not survive a round-trip conversion. For `double`, the limit is 15 significant digits.

Here is how we find the limits. A 24-bit significand can represent 2<sup>24</sup> values. That is 16,777,216, so it is certainly capable of representing all seven-digit decimal numerals from 0 to 9,999,999. However, if we want to represent some seven-digit decimal numeral *a*.*bcdefg*•10<sup>*n*</sup>, the last decimal numeral in this interval, 9.999999•10<sup>*n*</sup>, has some `float` representation *f*•2<sup>*e*</sup>. Because the powers of 10 are irregular relative to the powers of two, that *f* might be small, meaning that we are not representing the numbers from 0.000000•10<sup>*n*</sup> to 9.999999•10<sup>*n*</sup> with significands entirely in a single sequence 0 to 16,777,215. (I am glossing over some details here; numbers which would have significands under 2<sup>22</sup> are rescaled to another exponent in the normal range. But being in a finer exponent range gives more precision, so that is not an issue.) Rather, there was a rollover at some point, and the exponent increased. So we lose one bit of precision. So the number of decimal digits we can guarantee survive a round-trip conversion to a floating-point format with *p* digits in base *b* is floor((*p*−1)•log<sub>10</sub>*b*). (That formula is given in C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 12.)

Comment: Eric : Here's a question on a similar topic I think you could answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538534 .