# Which numbers can safely be converted into JavaScript numeric type?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Given a backend that sends numbers with either 4 or 6 digits after the decimal point, will these numbers always be exactly converted to JavaScripts number type (during JSON deserialisation)? Which numbers will cause problems?

Hint: assume the backend is precise, no rounding errors etc. I need to understand at which point problems can occur on the frontend though.

Comment: why would they change, they are decimal values not strings that will be formatted

Comment: @R.LM Couldn't there be some rounding errors while converting them to JavaScripts number type (or later converting them from number type to string)

Comment: number is just a name that allows users not to have to worry about the type of number used, but on the system a value won't be change magically unless you ask it to change

Comment: I think you're just asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Frame challenge: do you need them *as numbers*? If you're only going to display them, then you can pass them as strings and never worry about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I need to think more about it and likely ask a more specific question.

Comment: @VLAZ I think this is a fair question. Is there a possibility of getting a different number when a decimal with 6 places is parsed? This is not the same as 0.1+0.2 OR other math operations.

Comment: JS (double-precision floating point) numbers have around 16 decimal digits of accuracy. How many of them are before or after the decimal point does not matter, you need to count both sides. So as long as you have <=10 digits before and <= 6 digits after the point, you'll be fine.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that goes directly in the direction I need to understand. Can you provide more details? E.g. which number would just still work and which one wouldn't anymore?

Comment: @Bergi I think you should post this as an answer

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Character_representation

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, will have a look at that. As suggested by adiga, please consider posting as answer. Obviously you are into this topic :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bergi's comment:

> JS (double-precision floating point) numbers have around 16 decimal digits of accuracy. How many of them are before or after the decimal point does not matter, you need to count both sides. So as long as you have <=10 digits before and <= 6 digits after the point, you'll be fine. – Bergi

However, as Eric Postpischil remarked in an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535592/concept-related-to-precision-of-float-and-double/67536992#67536992), saying that a `double` or `float` format has "some number of decimal digits is sloppy terminology". Because `double` and `float` typically correspond to numbers in binary, not decimal (more specifically, IEEE 754 binary64 and binary32, respectively), and not all decimal numbers can be converted to binary numbers without loss.