# Conversion safety for numbers received from JSON API

Tags: javascript, c#, numbers, decimal

I have a backend that sends numbers with up to 19 digits before the decimal point and 6 digits after the decimal point. The backend is exact and correctly converts these digits into JSON like

```
{
  myNumber: 9999999999999999999.123456
}
```

On the frontend I use JavaScript and the standard fetch API `response.json()`.

1. By default the `myNumber` is converted into JavaScripts `number` type by `response.json()`. Can there be any loss of precision during this conversion?
2. Later on I might convert the `number` type back to string. Can there be any loss of precision during this conversion?

I need to understand which numbers can be safely converted from (a) the JSON representation to (b) JavaScripts number type and (c) back to a string. In which ranges will (a) and (c) be identical, when will I run into issues?

I hope I abstracted that enough away, but in case anyone is interested: The backend is C# Web API with SQL Server which uses DECIMAL(19,6).

Comment: A simple test in the console in Chrome showed that doing: `9999999999999999999.123456.toString();` produced -> `"10000000000000000000"` and doing `new Number("9999999999999999999.123456")` produced `10000000000000000000`

Comment: @RyanWilson well `9999999999999999999 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `true`, so it's hardly surprising.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks? I was just pointing out that this can be easily tested. I don't think this post was necessary.

Comment: @RyanWilson evidently OP did not consider it. Teaching how to 
f̶i̶s̶h̶ check *any* number for safety seemed relevant alongside giving them 
f̶i̶s̶h̶ the information that this one number is not safe.

Comment: I want to thank you both, I didn't think of the test by Ryan and I wasn't aware of the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` :-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538240/which-numbers-can-safely-be-converted-into-javascript-numeric-type

Answer (score 3):

Basically, use strings instead of JSON numbers. [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-6) states:

> This specification allows implementations to set limits on the range
> and precision of numbers accepted.  Since software that implements
> IEEE 754 binary64 (double precision) numbers [IEEE754] is generally
> available and widely used, good interoperability can be achieved by
> implementations that expect no more precision or range than these
> provide, in the sense that implementations will approximate JSON
> numbers within the expected precision.  A JSON number such as 1E400
> or 3.141592653589793238462643383279 may indicate potential
> interoperability problems, since it suggests that the software that
> created it expects receiving software to have greater capabilities
> for numeric magnitude and precision than is widely available.

The numbers you're dealing with have significantly more digits than IEEE-754 double precision will preserve.

If you use a string in the JSON like this:

```json
{
    "myNumber": "9999999999999999999.123456"
}
```

... then you can handle the conversion to/from any high/arbitrary-precision type yourself; it's completely in your control.

Comment: See also RFC 7493, "The I-JSON Message Format", section 2.2.